# Join multiple Rows as columns with many where and having clauses

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to solve (a complex?) Problem, which I can't get to work on my own.

I got the following Tables: (Coordinates are dummys)

Table A:

```
ID | Name    |Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 | Lat | Lon | Car Country
1  | Test 1  | Blue       | BMW         | 6.4 | 6.2 | German
2  | Hallo   | Red        |Porsche      | 6.4 |6.2  | German
3  | Miau    | Silver     |Ferrari      | 2.5 | 1.4 | Italy
```

Table B

```
ID |ID Car|  Slot |  Path
1  |  1   |  1    |jsjf.jpg
2  |  2   |  1    | hkfu.jpg
3  |  2   |  2   | eqfwg.png
```

User can upload a Car with attributes and a coordinate and with unlimited pictures. Pictures are then saved in the Table B with the path, Slot (first Image, second image, ...) and the car it's belonging to.

So now i want to get every car within my radius and the first 3 images. As a Result for the coordinates 6.4&6.2 I need:

```
ID | Name   | Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 | image1   | image2    |image3
1  | Test 1 | Blue        | BMW         | jsjf.jpg | Null      | Null
2  | Hallo  | Red         | Porsche     | hkfu.jpg | eqfwg.png | Null
```

My Query at the moment is:

```
SELECT
   a.id,
   a.name,
   a.attribute1,
   a.attribute2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN b.slot= 1 THEN b.path ELSE NULL END) image1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN b.slot= 2 THEN b.path ELSE NULL END) image2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN b.slot= 3 THEN b.path ELSE NULL END) image3,
(
    6371 * acos(
        cos(
            radians( 6.4 )
        ) * cos(
            radians( lat )
        ) * cos(
            radians( lon ) - radians( 6.2 )
        ) + sin(
            radians( 6.4 )
        ) * sin(
            radians( lat )
        )
    )
) AS distance

FROM
a
 left join bon a.id=b.idcar


WHERE carcountry= 'German'
HAVING
  distance <= 50

ORDER BY
   distance asc LIMIT 0, 10
```

Without the Max() and join everything works....

Answer (score 0):

You can not solve this with aggregation. You can do multiple left joins, one for each of the images, including the `slot = n` clause in the `ON` of the join, so:

```
SELECT (...), image1.file as image1, image2.file as image2, (...)
FROM 
    a 
    LEFT JOIN image image1 ON slot=1 AND a.id=image1.idcar
    LEFT JOIN image image2 ON slot=2 AND a.id=image2.idcar
```

Of course it will prove helpful to include `slot` in an index together with the foreign key. Also, it might be more efficient to simply query all images and restructure your data in the application logic; LEFT JOINS tend to be expensive. I'd advise to put some time into measuring that.

I think it might also be solvable with a join on a subquery with doing subselects, but I wouldn't do that as it tends not be more efficient and its will cost you legibility.

Comment: The foreign key is the ID of Table A? If so, how do I set it? ATM I just indexed the primary key of each table...
I don't think that quering every Picture of this product and then sorting it with PHP is more efficient than selecting with mysql

Comment: This doesnt work as it says "Unknown column 'b.idcar' in 'on clause' "

Comment: You should use `image1.idcar`, I'll fix that in my answer (i.e., the alias of the joined table should be used, not the table name itself)